# Google Guava - Filter a Collection by the value of one if it's element's properties relative to another element's

Tags: java, guava, jodatime

Really poorly worded title for my first question here, but hopefully I'll still get an answer to it!

What I would like to have is to be able to chain what the `filterIt`-method in the following code-snippet does into my existing `FluentIterable`.

I'm VERY new to Guava (at least the functional programming part of it), so please bear with me.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

import java.util.Set;

public class Blah {
    private DateTime date;

    private Blah(final DateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Blah> blahs = Sets.newHashSet(
                new Blah(DateTime.now()),
                new Blah(DateTime.now().minusDays(10)),
                new Blah(DateTime.now().minusDays(21)),
                new Blah(DateTime.now().minusDays(15))
        );

        Set<Blah> filteredBlahs = filterIt(blahs);

        final int filtered = blahs.size() - filteredBlahs.size();

        System.out.println(filtered + " results were filtered out");
    }

    private static Set<Blah> filterIt(final Set<Blah> blahs) {
        final Set<Blah> filteredBlahs = Sets.newHashSet();

        for (Blah currentBlah : blahs) {
            final DateTime currentDate = currentBlah.date;

            for (Blah blah : blahs) {
                if (blah != currentBlah && !filteredBlahs.contains(blah)) {
                    final Days days = Days.daysBetween(currentDate, blah.date);

                    if (Math.abs(days.getDays()) < 5) {
                        filteredBlahs.add(currentBlah);
                        filteredBlahs.add(blah);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return filteredBlahs;
    }
}
```

This code is written quickly as an example for what I want implemented. My problem is that I want this type of filtering to happen in the middle of some other transformations, and being able to chain it instead of splitting it up into different `Iterables` would make the flow more understandable at a glance.

Any feedback on how I can better the question, or clarify it, would be very much welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO.

To elaborate: You could write `Function`s to extract the date, you could write `Predicates` to test them, but even if you've found the way to stick them together, it would be a mess because of [all those caveats](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained). You'd have to wait for JDK8 in order to make something at least remotely readable out of it.

The other thing is that you're testing pairs of `Blah`s (+1 for the name), which goes really too far for a general purpose library. Imagine the myriads of methods like this.

The last thing is that what you're doing is not really functional: Your condition depends on the `filteredBlahs` list, which changes during the iteration. That's fine, if you need it, but converting this into something functionally-looking would be an obfuscation.

Predicates used for filtering really shouldn't change in the process, otherwise you can run in undefined or confusing behavior like in [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1543).

Comment: Yeah, I figured something like this would be the answer, but I though it was worth giving it a try. Thanks!